# How to identify which missing Java Libraries to make JAXB to work?

Tags: java, jaxb, businessworks

My Tibco BW 6.3.2 project invokes some Java Code that works on my machine, but I'm having issues on the server.

At first, I got this error

```
 <CausedBy> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader cannot be found
```

So Googled it and added `jaxb-impl.jar` and `jaxb-core.jar`(JAXB v2.2.11). Again, it worked on my machine without adding these to the classpath. But once I added them, I got this error on the server:

```
<CausedBy> java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created
<CausedBy> java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
```

Again, I Googled it and added `xercesImpl.jar`. But now I'm getting this on my machine & server :

```
<CausedBy> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
```

After some google searching, I've determined there are 2 `xerces` jars in my project, but I can't find the second one. Any thoughts on how to do that? OR does anyone have a different solution?

Side note, the java code works perfectly fine in Eclipse without any of these libraries added to the class path. (All devices are using Sun JDK 1.8.0_92)

Comment: so why you add them then?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer - Because I'm getting the errors and my program wont run.

Comment: The Xerces library might be already loaded by the classloader of the container, what server are you running? Maybe have a look in the lib directory of your application server?

Comment: Furthermore, I would mavenize your project and add the jaxb-impl and jaxb-core dependencies and check the maven dependency tree with `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`. If it works on the commandline without Eclipse, you eliminated the possibility that Eclipse had something on the classpath you were not aware of and it's probably the server that loaded the extra libs.

Comment: @NickVanderhoven - That could be, but I can't find it. I'm running Windows 2012 R2 with Tibco BW 6.3.2 & TEA 2.2.

Comment: @NickVanderhoven Unfortunately, I don't have access to maven yet....

Comment: A lazy solution could be do print `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` and compare the list of libraries in the path.

Comment: @SubOptimal nickname checks out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: 
I removed all the jaxb libraries I added and defined them in the Module Descriptors -> Dependencies -> Imported Packages.

[image: Imported Packages]

Comment: Since Java-6 JAXB (packages `javax.xml.bind..., com.sun.xml.bind...`) is included in the JRE, so that there is no need for the `jaxb-impl.jar` and `jaxb-core.jar` dependencies anymore.
Also since Java-6 a Xerces clone (packages `com.sun.org.apache.xerces...`) is included in the JRE and used by JAXB. Therefore, having the original Xerces (packages `org.apache.xerces...`) as an additional dependency would do more harm than good.